# How to open/read a DBF file on python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am getting an error when I write this code

```
from dbfread import DBF 
for record in DBF("filename.dbf"):     
print(record)
```

and the error that i get is:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message you're encountering suggests that the 'ascii' codec is unable to decode some characters in the file you're trying to read. This is most likely because the file uses a different encoding that contains characters not representable in the ASCII character set.

To resolve this issue, you can try specifying the encoding used in the file when you create the DBF object. For example:

```
from dbfread import DBF
for record in DBF("filename.dbf", encoding='utf8'):
    print(record)
```

Note that the actual encoding used in your file might be different, you can check the encoding of your file and use the appropriate one.

Comment: well i'm getting the error:

Comment: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 1: invalid start byte

Comment: Add the actual encoding used in your file. Is that utf-8?

Comment: any clue how to deal with that?

Comment: how can i check the actual encoding? (sorry for the silly questions)

Comment: To check the actual encoding of a dbf file using Python, you can use the dbf module. Here is an example:

import dbf

dbf_file = dbf.Table("path/to/dbf_file.dbf")
encoding = dbf_file.encoding
print("The actual encoding of the dbf file is:", encoding)

dbf_file.close()

Comment: import dbf 
dbf_file = dbf.Table("TERMIN02.DBF") 
encoding = dbf_file.encoding() 
print("The actual encoding of the dbf file is:", encoding) 
dbf_file.close()

Comment: AttributeError: 'Db3Table' object has no attribute 'encoding'

Comment: What happens with 
`for record in DBF("filename.dbf", encoding='latin1'):
    print(record)` ??